# Drupal 7 Views list, add link

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

Currently I have a Drupal installation which has colorbox installed, this allows me to upload a group of images with some text, each entry is its own entity but are all listed on the same page.

I was just wondering if there is a way that I can display a custom link under each views item (entity). Is this possible?

I'm looking for a quick way to simply add a link that links to the first image of the colorbox image slider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, set your `Format` to `Show: Fields`.  To do so, click the link next to `Show:` (refer to the picture below) and change it to `Fields`.

[image]

If your `Format` is set to `Show: Fields`, you can add a new field of type `Global: Custom text`.  Then, in the text box that appears, simply insert your custom link.  If you need to pull in the URL dynamically, use a **Replacement Pattern** (see the list under the text box).

If you need to use another field as a replacement pattern, add it in the same way as you added the `Global: Custom text` field but make sure to check the `Exclude from display` checkbox so that it is not shown in your view.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, how do i change the format to show fields? im not sutre hwat you mean. thank you for your help

Comment: awesome, thanks heaps ill give it a shot. i just need that link to do the same thing that the colourbox image does when you click on it. so when i click on the image the lightbox shows up, i pretty much need that same functionality when you click on the link under it. this sounds like it would do that. is that correct? thank you!